# Notification Listener - onNotificationPosted doesn't work

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, notification-listener

I'have tried all kind of solutions and code but any of this solutions worked for me, and I don't know why. Please help me.

My MainActivity code is:

```
if(isNotificationServiceEnabled())
    {
        Intent i= new Intent(this,NotificationsService.class);
        i.putExtra("command", "get_status");
        startService(i);
    }
    else
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
```

Now I'm just tryng to check if the service read a nostification posted, but from log i can only see that it enters in **onCreate** method but no in **onNotificationPosted**.

This is the code for my service class:

```
public class NotificationsService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onListenerConnected(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(final StatusBarNotification sbn){

    Log.d(TAG,"got it");

}
```

I have tried also solutions with broadcast service , but it still doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask for permission and grant permission for your app?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Yes In mainActivicty I check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solutions. In my code I had some problems, but then I tested other code about notification listener in an other project, and It worked. So then I modify my code and now it works.

About notification lisener You don't need to launch the service, because when you launch the app the service is launched. So I just made this changes to my code:

Main

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(!isNotificationServiceEnabled())
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
    }

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And in the service I just put the log code to write in debug the notification package.

Instead I got that broadcast are just used to exchange the data between service and my activity, for example to write the notifications in a textview.

Comment: What exactly do you do in the `isNotificationServiceEnabled()` method?